# Starting Another Class Program in Current StackPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

Currently im writing a program for inserting, searching and updating data within a database in JavaFX.

I would really like to have the three different tasks run in the one Panel. I have an insert class that runs fine but when called opens a new window instead. How do i make it run in the current java stack pane once a button is clicked?

Can send images if needed.

**Code**

```
private Object ShowInsert() { 
    //trying to run ProcessGrades in the middle of the stack pane named
    MidStack ProcessGrades p1 = new ProcessGrades(); 
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage(); 
    p1.start(primaryStage);

    MidStack.getChildren().add(p1); //didnt work as p1 is not a node
    middle.setText("you clicked insert!"); 
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: could I email you code instead with pictures?

Comment: You can add the pictures along with the code in your question.

Comment: //When I click the show insert button
 private Object ShowInsert() {
  //trying to run ProcessGrades in the middle of the stack pane
named MidStack   
  ProcessGrades p1 = new ProcessGrades();
  Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
  p1.start(primaryStage);
  
  //MidStack.getChildren().add(p1);...............didnt work as p1 
is not a node
  
  middle.setText("you clicked insert!");
  return null;
 }

"How do i post pictures? Im new to this, thanks"

Comment: Always edit your question with code, instead of adding them as a comment. You can upload your images to imgur or any other image hosting site and attach links to question.

Comment: could you explain how to upload images? first time using this site. Also do you understand my question?

Example is shown on this website 
under figure 3-1
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/style_css.htm

Comment: @Brad094 [Please refer to the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). The last entry is about images.